# call random values for drawing shapes and removing shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My program uses Turtle to draw shapes. It shows the following menu:

1. Enter Circle
2. Enter Rectangle
3. Remove Shape
4. Draw Shapes
5. Exit

If the user enters "4", the program should draw the shapes in the order they are in the list.

**[PROBLEM]**: So it should draw a circle and a rectangle with random values. I am having problems trying to do that as well as removing the shapes if the user enters "3". I have left an example of the way I am approaching Drawing Shapes using the random function for circle.

Also, what should my code be if choice == 3 (removing the shapes)?

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import turtle
import random

def circle():
    turtle.pensize(1)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, yCoordinate)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.circle(radius)

    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.done()

def rectangle():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(colorRectangle)
    turtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    turtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    turtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    turtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)


    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.done()

def remove():
    pass

def shapes():
    turtle.pensize(1)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x.random, yCoordinate.random)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(random)
    turtle.circle(radius.random)


COMMANDS = [None, circle, rectangle, remove, shapes, exit]
ABORT = len(COMMANDS) - 1
PROMPT = "1. Draw a circle\n2. Draw a rectangle\n3. Remove Shapes\n4. Draw Shapes\n5. Quit"

while True:
    choice = turtle.numinput("Pick a number", prompt=PROMPT, default=ABORT, minval=1, maxval=ABORT)

    if choice == 1:
        x = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yCoordinate = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        radius = int(input("Enter the Radius: "))
        color = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green): "))
        xCoordinate = (x - radius)

    if  choice == 2:
        xRectangle = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yRectangle = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        height = int(input("Enter Height: "))
        width = int(input("Enter Width: "))
        colorRectangle = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green):  "))

    if choice == 3:
        print(1)

    if choice == 4:
        print(shapes)

    if choice is None:
        choice = ABORT
    else:
        choice = int(choice)

    if 1 <= choice <= ABORT:
        COMMANDS[choice]()

turtle.mainloop()  # never reached
```

Comment: What are your problems exactly?

Comment: "if choice == 3" and "if choice == 4". How to remove shapes and how to Draw Shapes (Circle and Rectangle (in that order)) using random values.

Comment: Keep a list of all shapes. For 3, use a random integer with `random.randint()`, delete the item at the random index from your list. For 4, generate a random integer in a similar way, if the random integer is 1, create a rectangle, with 2 a circle, and so on.

Comment: But I don't want to call my shapes randomly and simply draw them. I need the values for the circles and rectangles to be random. E.g., random radius, random width, random height, and random coordinates. The program should draw a circle first and a rectangle second.

Comment: Then use `random.uniform(1,5)` for instance to create a radius between 1 and 5 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are missing parameters, also it a good practice to use "elif", it reduces the number of checks you make and will reduce logical errors as well

Also, make sure to refer back to the documentation for syntax help!
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.clear

I made some modifications to your code to achieve what you need

```
import turtle
import random

# Create a turtle object
myturtle = turtle.Turtle()

def circle(x, yCoordinate, radius, color):
    myturtle.pensize(1)
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(x, yCoordinate)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.pencolor(color)
    myturtle.circle(10)
    myturtle.hideturtle()

def rectangle(xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle):
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.pencolor(colorRectangle)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle + height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle + width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.goto(xRectangle - width / 2, yRectangle - height / 2)
    myturtle.hideturtle()


def rremove():
    myturtle.clear()

def shapes():
    myturtle.pensize(1)
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.goto(x.random, yCoordinate.random)
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.color(random)
    myturtle.circle(radius.random)


COMMANDS = [None, circle, rectangle, rremove, shapes, exit]
ABORT = len(COMMANDS) - 1
PROMPT = "1. Draw a circle\n2. Draw a rectangle\n3. Remove Shapes\n4. Draw Shapes\n5. Quit"
COLORS = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue',  'green']

while True:
    choice = turtle.numinput("Pick a number", prompt=PROMPT, default=ABORT, minval=0, maxval=ABORT)
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        x = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yCoordinate = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        radius = int(input("Enter the Radius: "))
        color = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green): "))
        xCoordinate = (x - radius)
        circle(x, yCoordinate, radius, color)

    elif choice == 2:
        xRectangle = int(input("Enter the X Coordinate: "))
        yRectangle = int(input("Enter the Y Coordinate: "))
        height = int(input("Enter Height: "))
        width = int(input("Enter Width: "))
        colorRectangle = str(input("Enter desired Color (choose red, yellow, blue or green):  "))
        rectangle(xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle)

    elif choice == 3:
        COMMANDS[choice]()

    elif choice == 4:
        #Here you can adjust the lower and upper bounds of the random number 
        x, yCoordinate, color, radius = random.randint(10,40), random.randint(10,200), random.choice(COLORS), random.randint(10,200)
        COMMANDS[1](x, yCoordinate, radius,color)
        print("Drew a circle")
        xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle = random.randint(10,200), random.randint(10,200), random.randint(10,200),random.randint(10,200), random.choice(COLORS)
        COMMANDS[2](xRectangle, yRectangle, width, height, colorRectangle)
        print("Drew a rectangle")

    elif choice == 5:
        COMMANDS[choice]()

    else:
        print("Invalid, try again...")
        continue
```

Comment: I cannot draw a circle or a rectangle now with your code, the "quit" option is not working anymore, remove shapes option gives me an error: "line 64, in <module>
    COMMANDS[choice]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float", and the draw shapes option only draws rectangles.

Comment: I didn't edit options 1 and 2, they're just missing function calls. Anyways here you go I added them for you. And for the delete, choice was a float, you have to parse it to int before using it as an index

Comment: The only one that it are not working is the "quit" option and the remove shapes option. How can I make them work?

Comment: Thank you! the "remove shapes" option works perfectly, but when I enter "5" to quit, it says "invalid, try again..."

Comment: No problem, try to put some effort, this issue was a matter of the conditional statement, all you needed to change was "if choice == 0"  to "if choice == 5"

Comment: You can pick the best answer if that solved your issue

Comment: Done! Thank you!